# How to disable caching for USB storage devices (by default), so that we can unplug without clicking eject?

Tags: usb, cache, eject

Is there any way to completely caching for USB storage devices (I mean for example 32GB USB Hard Drives, NTFS, FAT32 formatted etc.), for Linux? **(like Microsoft's Windows)**

People coming from **MS Windows** background are just removing the usb drive without ejecting it so the data corrupts.

I have only found solution for a mounted drive, but I want to make it default so there will be no ejecting problem in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: The mount option is sync. You then need to set it somewhere so that it sets this option for all USB attached storage devices.